# How was "Symptoms of Being Human" received by the queer community?

Tags: sexuality, reception, symptoms-of-being-human, jeff-garvin

*[Symptoms of Being Human](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/22692740-symptoms-of-being-human)* by Jeff Garvin tells the story of Riley, and the story of her navigating a new school, people bullying him, and being outed as genderfluid to their family.

Recently on Writing Twitter, there's been a lot of discussion about Ownvoices (a member of a marginalized community writing about their own community) stories. This made me think about *Symptoms*. Jeff - the author - is a cis man (so *Symptoms* is not Ownvoices). Given that there have been a not-insignificant number of people saying that especially trans stories<sup>1</sup> should be told by people who are actually members of the community, I'm wondering what the sentiment was at the time that the book was released.

How was *Symptoms of Being Human* received by the queer community in 2016, when the book was released?

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>Note that this is specifically *trans stories*, as opposed to *stories with trans characters*.</sub>